# Youtube preview in on-premises Newsfeed

Tags: 2013, video, newsfeed

I've seen a couple of demos where people add a YouTube link to their newsfeed, and a Facebook style thumbnail with a video preview is displayed. The same thing happens on my Office 365 account.

For some reason, my on-premises install of SP2013 is not doing that. It is just displaying the link as text. Does this not work on premises at all, or am I missing a config somewhere?

Comment: Can you check if thumbnails are appearing in search results when you perform a search

Comment: I get the preview of the conversation but I don't get any video thumbnail either.

Comment: Muhammad, Even for videos hosted in SharePoint, I get the thumbnail on the newsfeed, but not on the search preview

Comment: On my on-prem 2013 farm it simply shows up as a hyperlink - no thumbnail.

Comment: Having the same problem. It worked on O365, but isn't working on prem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As most of you know , SP2013 Newsfeed provides a cool feature wherin you get a Video thumbnail and an embedded player for links that you post from youtube. In most of the cases it works, but in some cases wherein you use a proxy server, this functionality doesn’t work. I tried to look at documentation on technet, but as usual nothing.

Solution:

So there are 2 stages to resolve this issues

1. Application Pool account needs access to the Internet

Login to the WFE’s servers on your SP2013 Farm and then put in the proxy information, so that the account is able to access the  internet. Test it by visiting, https://youtube.com. Repeat this step on all WFE’s. This resolves part of the error and you are now able to connect to gdata.youtube.com to get thumnail information and SP Attachement class is now able to build the complete JSON object. However, the video thumbnail will still not work because the SP Farm needs to trust the website using the *.google.com certificate

2. Enable Trust between SPFarm and Youtube.

On one of the WFE server, visit https://youtube.com and on the IE Browser, click on the lock icon in the address bar and download the certification(by clicking on details–>Copy to File, accept the defaults and store it on the local computer of your WFE server with yourfilename.cer).

Once you have this cert go to Central Administration–>Security–>Manage Trust, click new, give it some name and browse to the cer file you just downloaded and click OK.

Once this is done, go to you cer file on your local computer, double click it, Install Certificate and just follow the default prompt, the import will add the Certificate in your trusted root. Make sure to use Local Computer and not local user.

Repeat Step 1 and 2 on all of your WFE servers in the SP Farm.

Go back to your site and now the video embedded URL’s should be working"

Copied from the link shared by user 34659. It was wrong to just post a link, but it was indeed the solution for the problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your talking about embedding videos?

> If you type in a link to a youtube or video you have stored on your
>   SharePoint site you get a very cool preview automatically generated
>   for you:

[image: embedding video]

http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2012/07/social-in-sharepoint-2013-newsfeed-posting-and-replying/

follow these steps:

> You can embed videos from YouTube and similar services in a newsfeed
>   post. The process for doing this is similar to the one described above
>   for including links to Web pages. You paste a link to the video into
>   the post and optionally replace it with display text. A video
>   thumbnail appears in the post ready for you and others to run in a
>   video player.

1.Go to the video in its service and copy its URL to the clipboard.

2.In your newsfeed, paste the video URL into a new post, and press Enter.
You see a thumbnail for the video, and an option to format the video URL with display text.

[image]

3.If you want, type in display text for the video URL, and click the check mark.

[image]

4.Click Post to complete the newsfeed entry.

[image]

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-help/add-features-to-a-newsfeed-post-HA102785751.aspx#_Toc328036827

Comment: Yes Ali, I'm talking about embedding videos. Like I said, it works on my office 365 account, but not on premises. Can you confirm that it works in your on-premises farm, and if you had to do any specific configuration?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a proxy server, this error occurs, here is an detailed explanation
http://sharepointjournal.com/2014/10/29/sharepoint-2013-newsfeed-not-showing-video-preview-thumbnails/

Comment: Links tend to break over time rendering link-only answers useless. Please summarize the steps required to resolve the problem and use the link as a reference.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a proxy in your company? The app-pool-account needs internet access to generate the preview, check the proxy settings for that user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, along with error 8311 in the events related to certificate validation issue with `*.google.com`

The following worked for me:

- Go to gmail.com, view the certificate (the lock in IE) and download the root certificate "Geo Trust Global CA"
- Import the certificate in the computer certificate store under "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"

Now all the links from youtube display the thumbnail / preview